# AzureDevOps Error The type or namespace name 'MyNamespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: dll, build, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

This is not a duplicate. 
I am creating a build pipeline in AzureDevOps for my Asp.Net c# Application, which is using Git as the source repository. 
The aplication is having few external dlls, which are not available in Nuget. These dlls are placed in a project folder with name dependencies and is referred from there.
The application builds fine in all developer machines.
When the build pipeline is the build fails with below error.

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyNamespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is happening for all the external dependency references.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, is there good news to try with use relative path called in csproj? Free to leave comment below if you still having any error or puzzle:-)

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Thanks for your help. I have posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution that I found, since this can help someone.
Make sure the dependencies are available.

For me, I was using Git LFS for dlls. The dlls were not getting checked out by default, which was causing the issue.

I have added below lines, which resolved the issue.

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  lfs: true
```

The solution was to check out the lfs explicitly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not share how do you construct and use these dlls in your `.csproj`. But, there must somewhere incorrect to cause this error.

Create a folder under your solution, put these external dlls into this folder.

**Note**: Ensure the .csproj use the **relative paths** instead of using full paths. See this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/277436/view.html).